# How to include GWT Generated files in mvn:package

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, smartgwt

So I am trying to convert and existing maven project over to SmartGWT. I have GWT working but SmartGWT has some kind of problem working with Chrome and GWT doesn't work with firefox 8+ (I have 9). So I am not very good with GWT but my understanding is I should be able to get SmartGWT to work if I can deploy a compiled verison. I tried using mvn package but that doesn't include the GWT files in the JAR.

How do you package a Jar with the GWT files using Maven so it can be run on tomcat?

update:

`mvn clean compile gwt:compile package` worked for me

Comment: You could answer that and then accept it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of always entering the full build command `mvn clean compile gwt:compile package`, you, you could also bind the `gwt:compile` goal to the `prepare-package` phase, so that it will run just before the package phase (and after the testing goals have completed, among others), so you can just run `mvn package` (or `mvn clean package`, which would be closer to what you have above). Add an execution to the gwt-maven-plugin definition, something like this

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things to help out.  One is to install smartGWT into your local maven repository so it's sources and jar are available for builds.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/smart-gwt.jar -Dsources=path/to/smart-gwt.jar -Dversion=1.2.3 -DgroupId=group-id-to-use -DartifactId=smart-gwt -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar
```

Replace the values with whatever you want, so long as the version and path to jar is correct.  Now just include it as you would with any other dependency; use the groupId and artifactId you made up.

Next, if you want to use smart-gwt source instead of jar, you can generate a gwt-friendly jar of your own that has bundled sources. Setup an exportModule as follows

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<!--...-->

<build>
 <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
 <testSourceDirectory>tests/main/java</testSourceDirectory>

<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.java</include>
      <include>**/*.json</include>
      <include>**/*.png</include>
      <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/super/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.java</include>
      <include>**/*.json</include>
      <include>**/*.png</include>
      <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <filesets>
        <fileset><directory>war</directory></fileset>
        <fileset><directory>gwt-unitCache/</directory></fileset>
      </filesets>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

You can install your own gwt jar with the above module, assumed to be named exportModule using the command

```
 mvn -f exportModule/pom.xml clean install
```